# Creating a Site Collection - Get "Error in resolving user"

Tags: site-collection, people-picker, 2013, trusted-domain

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment in a DEV_DOMAIN that was upgraded from SharePoint 2010

COMPANY_DOMAIN should have a trust set up with DEV_DOMAIN.

I'm logged into the site as COMPANY_DOMAIN\first.last

When I create a site collection I get the following error in the logs

> Error in resolving user 'COMPANY_DOMAIN\first.last' :
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E):
>   Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.       at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()     at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()     at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean
>   findMoreThanOne)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.SearchFromGC(SPActiveDirectoryDomain
>   domain, String strFilter, String[] rgstrProp, Int32 nTimeout, Int32
>   nSizeLimit, SPUserCollection spUsers, ArrayList& rgResults)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUserUtility.ResolveAgainstAD(String
>   input, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly, SPActiveDirectoryDomain
>   globalCatalog, SPPrincipalType scopes, SPUserCollection
>   usersContainer, TimeSpan searchTimeout, String customFilter)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPActiveDirectoryPrincipalResolver.ResolvePrincipal(String
>   input, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly, SPPrincipalType scopes,
>   SPPrincipalSource sources, SPUserCollection usersContainer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal(SPWeb
>   web, SPWebApplication webApp, String input, SPPrincipalType scopes,
>   Boolean inputIsEmailOnly).

My first guess is there is some sort of issue with the trust between the domains, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

**Update 1**
It is using claims based authentication.

I can create the site collection using a DEV_DOMAIN account and setting the site collection admin to be a DEV_DOMAIN account, but if I set site collection admin to be a COMPANY_DOMAIN account it fails.

If I try to add a COMPANY_DOMAIN account as a user to the newly created site collection it cant find any users in that domain.

Running stsadm command for people picker and the result looks correct.

```
stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -url http://site
```

results in

```
<Property Exist="Yes" Value="forest:COMPANY_DOMAIN.com.au,COMPANY_DOMAIN\user1,*****; forest:DEV_DOMAIN.Company.local,DEV_DOMAIN\user2,*****" />
```

Comment: Is the web application using claims based authentication? Considering its 2013 it will almost force you to use that model rather than the classic mode auth that was the default in 2010

Comment: Yes it is claims based authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple.

> DEV_DOMAIN\user2 user account had expired

It had actually expired a while ago, it appears that in SharePoint 2010 the account doesn't actually authenticate it is just used. But in SharePoint 2013 the account does attempt to authenticate

Comment: Please mark as answer if it fixed your problem. Thanks!