# Error changing collection administrator

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, error, administration

Our environment is SharePoint 2013.  I'm trying to change a collection administrator to DOMAIN\Username. However it fails, and looking up the correlation ID in the logs, I see this exception:

> ERROR:  Error in resolving user 'DOMAIN\Username' :
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E):
> The user name or password is incorrect.       at
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) ...

I've installed RSAT and am able to browse Active Directory just fine, running as the SharePoint admin account. I've also run LDP and successfully connected to both Active Directory and Global Catalog. I also did the same with the SharePoint service account. So it's not that the accounts SharePoint is using don't have access to AD.

I'm really not sure what user name and password it's using to attempt the Bind.  Any idea where this is configured, so I can try to update the credentials?

Thanks!

Update

After posting the question, Stackoverflow offered a [related answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53192/creating-a-site-collection-get-error-in-resolving-user?rq=1) in the right sidebar.  Based on the stsadm command there, I was able to see the credentials used to connect to our 2 AD forests.  (In the admin console, there's no way to see what's configured for the connections.)  And they were set to the account of a developer who left the company!  It just makes me tired when people do that.

Now just to figure out if this can be changed, or if I have to delete and re-create the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer was to run the Central Admin console in a different browser, where you could in fact see what's configured as the account that connects to AD for each of the connections.  Once there, it was easy to update them to a working service account.